# Setting footer in android at the end of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I was looking at an example from the below website.

[link for the layout](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/)

Has an wonderful tutorial on developing dashboard layout.

For Main Screen footer sits perfectly at the end of the layout but for other screens when I try to put footer it renders at the middle of the layout.

I have also attached the code for the better understanding.

this is for style.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="ActionBarCompat">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="DashboardButton">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff29549f</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>    

 <style name="FooterBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">#dedede</item>
</style>     
</resources>
```

this is for header(action_bar) actionbar_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
style="@style/ActionBarCompat" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is for footer bar footer_layout.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   style="@style/FooterBar"
   android:id="@+id/footerMenuOptions" >
<TextView android:text="www.facebook.com"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#606060"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the layout for the attached screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:background="#f8f9fe">
<include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout"/>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Events Screen"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ff29549f"/> 

</LinearLayout>   
 <include layout="@layout/footer_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

We can clearly see how the footer is getting in middle of the screen in the attached image.[image: footer rendering in between the layout]

Tried with setting with `RelativeLayout` but the same rendering problem

Tried with `LinearLayout` with setting
                `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and placing the include of the footer `<include layout="@layout/footer_layout">` in the Linear Layout but the same rendering problem.

Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `RelativeLayout` and use its `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above` for center contents and `android:layout_alignParentBottom` for `View` to stick to bottom
Do this way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/top_control_bar">
        <include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
         <include layout="@layout/footer_layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar">
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Events Screen"
                    android:textSize="25dip"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#ff29549f"/> 

    </LinearLayout>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks working perfectly, but I still get these messages
`Couldn't resolve resource @id/bottom_control_bar`
`Couldn't resolve resource @id/top_control_bar`
any idea why I am getting these messages.

Comment: thanks. cleaning did not work, I had tried this earlier also, but closing and opening of the layout many times worked and the message went away for resolving resource.